# W3C Validation Failed, Illegal character in path segment: space is not allowed

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

```
<img src="webpage photos/alcazar.jpg" alt="Alcazar Palace">
```

The error shown by validator: Bad value webpage photos/alcazar.jpg for attribute src on element img: Illegal character in path segment: space is not allowed.

As soon as I remove the spaces I try to replace them by hyphens or %20 as recommended by some online I get even more errors but the webpage functions.

What seems to be the problem here?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white space is not allowed in urls, you need to replace it with `%20`

> As soon as I remove the spaces I try to replace them by hyphens or %20 as recommended by some online I get even more errors

well the W3C validation service will complain about the absence of **doctype** declaration and the **title** element and the **lang** attribute

so when you check with more code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="webpage%20photos/alcazar.jpg" alt="Alcazar Palace">
</body>
</html>
```

you get `Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show.`

Answer (score 0):

The value of `src` includes a space which is not allowed as legal value. please move out the image to another place without any space in path, and re-link to it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PHP function `str_replace()` to replace the spaces with %20.
But you likely be better off using the PHP function `rawurlencode()` as it will encode anything else that should also be encoded.

Use `rawurlencode()` on the base name of the file name, or in your case, each directory name.  This will transform spaces to %20, among other things.

You don't want to include the directory seporators '/' in the call to `rawurlencode()` as they will also get transformed and not work correctly.